# searching for an id in an associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array in my php code.array is having 5 keys inside the array namely 
Id,name,brand,store,location.The array is containing around 10000 records.

i click on some link in homepage ,it passes some id no. like 1.Then that id should be searched in the associative array id column and related parameters should be pushed into a new array.
or if any other way .Please guide on this..

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="second.php?id=1">id</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can get the ID in your PHP script with `$_GET['id']`. Then access the array like so: `$array['id'][$theIDYouGotAbove]`.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the array?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a foreach loop from the sounds of it.

```
foreach ($yourArray as $element) {
  if ($element['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
    // This is the element you want, feel free to do stuff

    // Make sure to use this to stop looking through the array
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @BrandonWamboldt's solution for now.

But of course, you should change your array structure from:

```
[
    {
        id: ID,
        name: NAME,
        brand: BRAND,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

To:

```
{
    id:
    {
        id: ID,
        name: NAME,
        brand: BRAND,
        ...
    },
}
```

For precisely this reason.